# How do I correctly plot two columns of a dataframe when the size of data is huge?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have a dataframe of the format:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'TCTN':list('101','102','103',....,'STDEV')
         '0':[855days,626days,....,5911days],
         '1':[946days,485days,....,6040days],
         '2':[1242days,1985days,....,5974days],
         '3':[345days,1864days,....,6062days],
})
```

of 4997 rows × 229 columns for which i tried to plot columns TNTC vs STDEV using:

```
df3.plot(x='STDEV' ,y='TNTC',figsize=(20,5),style='o')
```

which gives me a plot like this:
[image: matplotlib plot]

but what i actually needed is the TNTC values on the Y axis. Is that not possible since there are 4997 rows? do i change the style of the plot to better fit the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `matplotlib` instead of `pandas` to do the plotting:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.scatter(df['STDEV'].values, df['TNTC].values)
```

Comment: i tried this but the error i get is  module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'scatter'

Comment: @DevarshiGoswami Are you importing `matplotlib` or `matplotlib.pyplot'?

Comment: i was importing only matplotlib. i did so as asked , i.e import matplotlib.pyplot :  
            plt.scatter(df3['STDEV'].values, df3['TCTN'].values)  but it produces the  
       TypeError: Cannot cast scalar from dtype('float64') to dtype('<m8[ns]') according to the rule 'same_kind'

Comment: Shouldn't it be 'TNTC' instead of 'TCTN'? The key error means that it can't find the column with the name 'TCTN'.

Comment: im sorry for that , although after changing that a new error pops up

Comment: TypeError: Cannot cast scalar from dtype('float64') to dtype('<m8[ns]') according to the rule 'same_kind'

Comment: Please search for an answer on other stack overflow questions, or create a new question.